# XCode autolayout not working with UIScrollView for horizontal paging

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm trying to create a horizontal paging by using AutoLayout. Here's the code.

```
 UIView *newsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    newsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIView *anotherNewsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    anotherNewsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    newsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    anotherNewsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:newsView];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:anotherNewsView];
 [self.scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:newsView
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:self.scrollView
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                   multiplier:1.0f
                                                                     constant:0.0f]];

    [self.scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:newsView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:self.scrollView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                               multiplier:1.0f
                                                                 constant:0.0f]];

    [self.scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:newsView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:self.scrollView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                               multiplier:1.0f
                                                                 constant:0.0f]];
//
    [self.scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:newsView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:anotherNewsView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                               multiplier:1.0f
                                                                 constant:0.0f]];
//    
    [self.scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:anotherNewsView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:self.scrollView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                               multiplier:1.0f
                                                                 constant:0.0f]];

    [self.scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:anotherNewsView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:self.scrollView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                               multiplier:1.0f
                                                                 constant:0.0f]];

    [self.scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:anotherNewsView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:self.scrollView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                               multiplier:1.0f
                                                                 constant:0.0f]];

    [self.scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:newsView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:anotherNewsView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                               multiplier:0.99f
                                                                 constant:0.0f]];
```

But I only see the `scrollView` which I set the background to cyan.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scroll View not functioning IOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502860/scroll-view-not-functioning-ios-7)

Comment: I tried the approach from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html which is the answer but it didn't really work. I'm going with the pure code approach.

Comment: I had the same issue and above solution worked like a charm, with minimal effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your views have width and height zero as they are configured right now.

Try adding some with and height constraints to them like :

```
NSArray *heightConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[view(height)]" options:0 metrics:@{ @"height":@(CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.frame)) } views:@{ @"view":newsView }];
[self.scrollView addConstraints: heightConstraints];

[self.scrollView addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[newsView(width)]" options:0 metrics:@{ @"width":@(CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.frame)) } views:@{ @"newsView":newsView]];

[self.scrollView addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[anotherNewsView(width)]" options:0 metrics:@{ @"width":@(CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.frame)) } views:@{ @"anotherNewsView":anotherNewsView }]];
```

You can also check one of my other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044917/auto-layout-uiscrollview-and-single-subview/29107682#29107682).

The important thing is that the views inside the `scrollview` must have their own width and height. This is how the `scrollView` calculates it's `contentSize`. If you don't have that, the `contentSize` will be `CGSizeZero` and you won't see your views.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks very much! I have been pulling my hair for days.

Comment: Sorry one quick question. After I applied your code , the red box's width is way longer than the screen size. I want the red box to be the first page and the blue box to be the second page. Not sure how to fit that perfectly. I updated the code here in case you want to look at the code https://github.com/noppanit/UIScrollViewAutoLayout

Comment: I changed to viewDidLayoutSubviews and it works perfectly! Thanks again.